# Patch versioning in Maven

Tags: maven, patch

We have an application which has a patched version released. Now we want to deploy this patched version with some classifier stating that it is a patch version and not a normal release.

So I was trying to test the plugin locally by installing it in the local maven repository and then building the project.

I used a command similar to this to install in the local repository.

```
mvn install:install-file  -Dfile=path/to/the/warfile -DgroupId=com.test.app -DartifactId=web-app -Dversion=default-version -Dpackaging=war -DlocalRepositoryPath=path/to/local/repo -Dclassifier=patch-version
```

Once the war file is installed in the local repo, I included a dependency in the pom file like this

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.test.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>web-app</artifactId>
        <version>default-version</version>
        <classifier>patch-version</classifier>
        <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

Now when I build the project using mvn clean package, the patched version war file is not picked up from the local repository. Instead it is downloading the default version i.e default-version from the project repository.

I want my project to use the patched version to build the project. Can someone point me to a correct usage or some other better way to do this.

Comment: I don't see any config in war plugin to include differnetly classified jars, you might want to check assembly plugin

Comment: as you say I would also expect this to work. I assume "default-version" is a placeholder? Is that a SNAPSHOT Version? It may be the version in the repo seems newer to maven. Or do you have several local repositories and just hit the wrong one?
Another way would be to just include the patch in the version itself like "1.0.0-EMERGENCYPATCH-01" not using the classifier at all. This allows maven to identify the artifact. Is the snippet withe dependency from the dependencyManagement section? Maybe you need to add the classifier in the actual dependency too.

Comment: Classifier is not intended to show that you created a patch version. A patch version should be marked by using a different version like `1.0` released and a patch version could be `1.0.1` etc.